# ItemSlide + Fancybox Supersized (launch Fancybox from within function)

Tags: jquery, fancybox, carousel

I'm trying to combine a carousel made with ItemSlide.js with Fancybox, extended to supersize.

Here is an example of Fancybox Supersized (without integration into ItemSlide)
http://jsfiddle.net/RyTcS/

ItemSlide can be found here:
http://itemslide.github.io/

What I'm trying to do is open an image from the carousel to expand full-page on tap/click using FancyBox Supersized.

My code at the moment is this:

```
// Start the carousel        
carousel_1 = $("#outfit_1");
carousel_1.itemslide({disable_clicktoslide:true});

// On tap, open Fancybox supersized
carousel_1.on('clickSlide', function(event) {
    console.log("Clicked - "+ event.slide);
    var image = $('#outfit_1 li').eq(event.slide).attr('data-image');
    console.log(image);
    $.fancybox({
        padding    : 0,
        margin     : 5,
        afterLoad  : function () {
            $.extend(this, {
                aspectRatio : false,
                type    : 'html',
                width   : '100%',
                height  : '100%',
                content : '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + image + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a JS Fiddle of my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8cwgpwdk/

It does not respond on click. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is a solution with FancyBox, to open fancybox simply use this method:

```
$.fancybox.open
```

Here is a jsFiddle (with afterload callback): http://jsfiddle.net/8cwgpwdk/14/

BTW part of the reason your first example didn't work is because you loaded FancyBox from github and they block so use a cdn instead. I fixed that as well.

Comment: Thanks @nir9 , but I can get Fancybox to work fine. It's only when I try to use it supersized, by extending Fancybox in the afterLoad callback that it does not work... Could you have a look?

Comment: Yah so here is a new version with the afterload callback - http://jsfiddle.net/8cwgpwdk/14/

Comment: Thanks man! Could you have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/RyTcS/ ? For some reason your example does not put the image 100% of the viewport and does not set it to cover...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in using FancyBox as what your trying to do is very simple to do with just jQuery.

```
$("#fullscreen").show().css("background-image","url("+image+")");
```

Here is a fixed version (Now works on mobile):
http://jsfiddle.net/8cwgpwdk/11/

Comment: Thanks! This makes it really nice and lightweight. Would like to see a solution in FancyBox aswel though, since I would like to use the next/previous function in it. Maybe even the caption aswel. But this is a good starting point. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, proposed solution gives some wonky behavior on mobile. I see a quick flash, but the image does not persist. It does on desktop (Chrome) though.

Comment: Yah that's because I didn't optimize it for mobile, so I made a fixed version here: http://jsfiddle.net/8cwgpwdk/11/

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you with the FancyBox solution because I'm not familiar with that library...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to award your bounty :-)